# Push NuGet Package to Artifactory local repo subfolder

Tags: nuget, artifactory

I have set up a local NuGet Repository [as described here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/NuGet+Repositories). The apikey is set and authentication is also set in the NuGet.Config file.

To push a nupkg directly into this folder, there is no problem:

```
nuget push Nuget.0.1.15.nupkg -Source http://arti.url/artifactory/api/nuget/nuget-repo-local
```

But as soon as I try to push it to a subfolder to have kind of a nice layout in Artifactory, this fails:

```
nuget push Nuget.0.1.15.nupkg -Source http://arti.url/artifactory/api/nuget/nuget-repo-local/aFolder
```

Is this a known problem, does anybody have a solution to this? Creating an apikey for every folder is not really what I am looking for...

The warning is as follows:

```
WARNING: No API Key was provided and no API Key could be found for 'http://arti.url/artifactory/api/nuget/nuget-repo-local/aFolder'. 
To save an API Key for a source use the 'setApiKey' command.
```

And the error says then:

```
Failed to process request. 'Forbidden'. 
The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden..
```

Comment: Default only a flat folder approach is supported. Look at [this](http://blog.nuget.org/20160113/Accelerate-your-NuGet.Server.html) blog post explaining how to accelerate the update process.

Comment: Not exactly what I am looking for. As one can see in the [documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/NuGet+Repositories#NuGetRepositories-PublishingtoaLocalRepository) it should be possible.

Comment: Regarding your error message with status code 403, it is more authentication/permission error related. If you go in your artifactory -> admin -> edit repository "nuget-repo-local" and tick the "Force Authentication" option the cli will ask for credentials and you will be able to authenticate and push to a subfolder as you tried to.

Comment: additionnal comment : the root cause is that you ran nuget setapikey on the repo itself but when you push to a subfolder nuget does not understand it as a subfolder but as another repo without apikey set in config.

Answer (score 6):

When you do :

```
nuget push Nuget.0.1.15.nupkg -Source http://arti.url/artifactory/api/nuget/nuget-repo-local/aFolder
```

nuget intrpret the whole url as the repo address (the client implementation is based on flat deployment where Artifactory is more flexible)

Regarding your deployment on root repo I assume you followed the indication and ran the setApiKey command first on the repo :

```
nuget setapikey <USERNAME>:<PASSWORD> -Source http://arti.url/artifactory/api/nuget/nuget-repo-local
```

this allow you to push without entering your credentials each time but only at root level.

Now if you want to push on subfolder you can set the apikey on it as you did for the rpo itself :

```
nuget setapikey <USERNAME>:<PASSWORD> -Source http://arti.url/artifactory/api/nuget/nuget-repo-local/aFolder
```

However you will have to do it on every folder

or use "apikey" option on push

```
nuget push Nuget.0.1.15.nupkg -Source http://arti.url/artifactory/api/nuget/nuget-repo-local/aFolder -apikey <USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>
```

or tick the option "Force authentication" on the repository configuration in Artifactory. This option will force you to enter your credentials and prevent your "403" error.